# C float literals - define in EBNF

Tags: c, floating-point, literals, ebnf

I am trying to figure out the correct way to write the EBNF description for a C float literal.

This is the one problem that I am stuck on. I am not sure how to write it because isn't float just a type? So far I am thinking it may just be

`float < literal >`

But that seems way too simple.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf See §6.4.4

Comment: More specifically, §6.4.4.2. (6.4.4 is constants in general; 6.4.4.2 describes floating constants specifically)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: n1124 has TC2 for C99; n1256 has TC3 for C99; n1570 is the most current C2011 draft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, from a viewpoint of a parser, a floating point ltieral would generally just be another token.

Figuring out that a particular sequence of input characters was a floating point literal would normally be done by the lexer. It's not as trivial as you'd like, but still pretty much a one-liner using a regex.